# Compute $\int_{\gamma}\frac{\log(1+z)}{ (z-\frac{1}{2})^3}dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, logarithms, complex-integration

> Compute
> $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{\log(1+z)}{(z-\frac{1}{2})^3}dz$$
>
> Where $\gamma:[0,2\pi]\to \Bbb{C}$ is given by $\gamma(t)=\frac{2}{3}e^{it}$.

Im quite confused in which branch of the logarithm should I use. And how should I proceed once I've chosen the correct one?

Comment: The real part of $1+z$ is positive on $\gamma$. Does that give you a hint of a good branch?

Comment: It doesn't matter which branch you use. What do you know about Cauchy's integral formula?

Comment: the integrand is well defined inside your contour of integration, so you don't have to care about branch cuts and all this stuff

Comment: I know the Cauchy integral formula! But I don't know when does it matter or not which branch you use!

Comment: What is $$\int_{\gamma} \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta-w)^{k+1}}\,d\zeta$$ if $f$ is holomorphic on a neighbourhood of the region enclosed by $\gamma$?

Comment: OK.  Then, choose a branch cut that doesn't intersect $\gamma$.  Observe that $\log (1+z)$ is analytic in and on $\gamma$.  Then apply the CIF noting the pole of third order.

Comment: $\frac{2\pi i f^{(k)}(w)}{k!}$ So I just have to chose a branch that doesn't go through $-1$?

Comment: @DanielFischer What if the branch cut of $\log$ is chosen to be on the positive real axis? Then $\log(1+z)$ won't be defined (or at least not holomorphic) for real $z$, $z>-1$. And this part will intersect $\gamma$ twice. I don't say it will be a real problem in the end, but I guess this is what OP wants to avoid.

Comment: @micep You're correct.  It won't matter since that particular branch cut intersects $\gamma$ twice.

Comment: @mickep If you have a branch-cut passing through your contour, that's always a problem. Since the OP asked "which branch" to use, and not "which branch-cut", I interpreted it as whether $\log 1 = 0$ or $\log 1 = 2\pi i$ or … Anyhow, while the result depends on whether the branch-cut passes through the contour, and if so where, the choice of branch [on a subset of the complement of the branch-cut] doesn't change the result as long as the domain of the chosen branch is simply connected.

Answer (score -2):

log(1+z) is analytic if we remove the ray (-inf,-1] and the given curve is in the resulting region. Thus from Cauchy formula f''(a)=2/2.pi.i.integral round C of f(z)/(z-a)^3 we get that the integral is (log(1+z))''.pi.i at z=1/2. It is i.pi.1/(9/4)

Comment: would you be so nice and work on the formatting of your answer?